# Implement a trie with insert, search, and startsWith methods in C from LeetCode.

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, trie

Implement a trie with insert, search, and startsWith methods.

Note:
You may assume that all inputs are consist of lowercase letters a-z.

I have written the very simple solution for implementing Trie in C, which has passed all the 16 test cases from LeetCode.

Any recommendation or suggestion for it ?

```
//node structure
struct TrieNode {
     char value;
     int count;
    struct TrieNode * children[27];
};


static int count =0;
/** Initialize your data structure here. */
//return root pointer
struct TrieNode* trieCreate() {
    struct TrieNode *pNode = NULL;

    pNode = (struct TrieNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct TrieNode));

    if (pNode)
    {
        pNode->value = '\0';
        pNode->count =0;

        memset(pNode->children, 0, sizeof(pNode->children));

    }
    return pNode;


}

/** Inserts a word into the trie. */
void insert(struct TrieNode* root, char* word) {

    struct TrieNode *pCrawl = root;
    count ++;
    //check if the word is not empty 
    if(word){
    int index=0, i =0;

    //check if the root is not empty
    if (root){

    while( word[i] != '\0'){
        index =  ( (int) (word[i]) - (int)'a');

        if(!pCrawl->children[index])
        {
            pCrawl->children[index] = trieCreate();
            pCrawl->children[index]->value = word[i];
        }

        pCrawl = pCrawl->children[index];
        i++;

    }

         //Count !=0 tell us that this is the last node;;
    pCrawl->count = count;

    }
}}



/** Returns if the word is in the trie. */
bool search(struct TrieNode * root, char* word) {

    struct TrieNode *pCrawl = root;
    bool flag = false;

    //check if word is NULL
    if(!word)
    return false;

    //if the trie is empty
    if(!root)
    {
        return false;
    }
    //if word is empty
    if (*word == '\0') {
        return true;
    }

    int i=0, index =0 ; 


    while (word[i] != '\0')
    {
     index = ((int) (word[i]) - (int)'a');

         //// if the node/character is not in Trie
        if(!pCrawl->children[index])
        {
            flag = false;
             break;
        }

        pCrawl = pCrawl->children[index];
        i++;
    }

          //count != 0 marks node as last / leaf node
          if(pCrawl->count != 0 && word[i] == '\0')
          {
              flag = true;
          }
        return flag;

}

/** Returns if there is any word in the trie 
    that starts with the given prefix. */
bool startsWith(struct TrieNode* root, char* prefix) {

    struct TrieNode * pCrawl = root;

    int i =0, index=0;
    bool flag = false;
    if(root){
    while(prefix[i] != '\0')
    {
         index = ((int) (prefix[i]) - (int)'a');

     if(pCrawl->children[index] == NULL){
     flag = false;
         return flag;
     }
     else 
     flag = true;

     pCrawl = pCrawl->children[index];
     i++;
    }

    }

    return flag;


}

/** Deallocates memory previously allocated for the TrieNode. */
void trieFree(struct TrieNode* root) {

    if(root){

        for(int i = 0; i <=26; i ++)
        {
            trieFree(root->children[i]);
        }
        free(root);

    }

}

// Your Trie object will be instantiated and called as such:
// struct TrieNode* node = trieCreate();
// insert(node, "somestring");
// search(node, "key");
// trieFree(node);
```

Comment: Maybe [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site would be a better place for this question.

Comment: Thanks . I have posted the same there.  Looking forward to improve my coding skills

Comment: "Any recommendation or suggestion for it ?" is not really a suitable question for StackOverflow. Please foucs on the specific programming problem you had when trying to solve this. It seems there is none. If you want to optimise this, please specify for what, you may refer to the list at the info for the "optimization" tag; https://stackoverflow.com/tags/optimization/info